# Multiple Comboboxes and parameter driven procedure

Tags: c#, excel, vba, combobox, excel-addins

I am trying to populate an Excel Worksheet with 100s comboboxes using via C# Excel Add-in. My issue is that I need to create a Genering procedure CmdBtn_Click() which will be called by each instance of the comboboxes and pass their Values and Names. In other words I need parameter driven procedure which will be called by the appropriate event. Can somebody suggest on how to do it in C#?

```
for (int i = 1; i < col + 1; i++)
{
    var comboRange = currentSheet.Cells[2, i];
var cmb_Column = (Excel.Shape)currentSheet.Shapes.AddOLEObject("Forms.ComboBox.1", 
        Type.Missing, 
        false, 
        false, 
        Type.Missing, 
        Type.Missing, 
        Type.Missing,
        Convert.ToInt32(comboRange.Left),
        Convert.ToInt32(comboRange.Top), 
        Convert.ToInt32(comboRange.Width), 
        Convert.ToInt32(comboRange.Height));

cmb_Column.Name = "cmb_Column" + i;

Excel.OLEObject oleComboBox = (Excel.OLEObject)cmb_Column.DrawingObject;
cb = Invoker.PropertyGet(oleComboBox, "Object") as MSForms.ComboBox;
cb.AddItem("Test1");
cb.Change += new MSForms.MdcComboEvents_ChangeEventHandler(CmdBtn_Click);
}


private void CmdBtn_Click()
{
    // Get the Change value of combobox as well as its name
}
```